# send daily email notifications using database mail

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my project , i have a functionality "Remind me daily" which is a checkbox
if a user sets the option checked , an email is to be sent daily using the database mail SQL Server 2008 untill a particular condition is met .
Please suggest how can i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, by a combination of a SQL Agent job and [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx). But I would recommend using [SQL Server Reporting Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) instead. It has the capability to create [data driven subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx) and [deliver them by email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334).

Answer (score 1):

Simple, create a new Sql Server Job and add the send mail task.
See this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/sending-automated-job-email-notifications-in-sql-server-with-smtp/

Best regards

Comment: This is how I've always done this. I just created a job with a single step. In that step, I added whatever logic needed to be present then shot an an email using DB Mail. I am not sure if you can even use SQL Mail in this manner but if you can, it is more difficult to setup and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the SQL Server Agent Mail feature.

more info at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188235%28v=sql.105%29.aspx